# eclipse plugin- Add extension only when a certain boolean in a class is true

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I´m currently developing an Eclipse plugin as my research project and I created an extension to the right-click menu of java editor. The problem is that this new extension always appears even when the user right-clicks on any part of the editor. I want to control its visibility in a way that the new extension only appears when a certain boolean in a class(which is a Singleton, by the way) is true. Is this possible? to add a menu contribution and set it visible only when a boolean in a class is true?

Answer (score 2):

You can't test a value in a class, but you can test a system property which a class can set using `System.setProperty()`.

Use

```xml
<systemTest property="property name" value="value"/>
```

in an expression (such as `<visibleWhen>`) to do the test.

You can also define a 'property tester' using the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point which could access the class.